# Zoom in on a point in an image in with VTK

Tags: java, image, vtk

I have an image in VTK that I'm viewing with vtkImageViewer2, and I want to zoom in on a point the user clicks on.  I am working in Java.  Does anyone know how to do this?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I realize you ask for Java, but my experience doing this has been with c++;  equivalent java syntax should work, minus the customizability.

Take a look at these examples for picking and zooming. Also, if you set the interactor style to 'image', the mouse wheel should cause a zoom to wherever the cursor is. You probably don't want to do literally what you asked, but rather either do rubberband zoom or have the mousewheel for zooming. Clicking should *do* something, not just change the view.

http://www.vtk.org/Wiki/VTK/Examples/Cxx/Images/PickingAPixel2

http://www.vtk.org/Wiki/VTK/Examples/Cxx/Interaction/RubberBandZoom

Answer (score 1):

Depending on what you mean by zoom you want to either change the **position** and direction of the camera (likely) or change the frustum (unlikely).

Have a look at the methods setPosition() and setFocalPoint() in class vtkCamera. Here is the documentation of vtkCamera:

> http://www.vtk.org/doc/nightly/html/classvtkCamera.html

Comment: I have looked at these methods before (in fact I implemented pan using them).  However, I'm not sure how to use them in conjunction with zoom() (the method I'm using to zoom).